# Geopandas sjoin() error: list index out of range

Tags: python, join, geopandas, shapely, index-error

I have two GeoDataFrames. One has Shapely points set as .geometry, the other one has Shapely polygons and multipolygons set as .geometry. When I try to use the `sjoin()` function on them, I get an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

points_gdf = pd.read_pickle('points.pickle')
polys_gdf = pd.read_pickle('polys.pickle')

# points_gdf.geometry consists of shapely points
# polys_gdf.geometry consists of shapely polygons and multipolygons

# Now, I use the sjoin() function

return_gdf = gpd.sjoin(points_gdf, polys_gdf, how="inner", op='intersects')
```

Then I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-e5b042f3f0e2> in <module>
----> 1 return_gdf = gpd.sjoin(points_gdf, polys_gdf, how="inner", op='intersects')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\sjoin.py in sjoin(left_df, right_df, how, op, lsuffix, rsuffix)
     73     tree_idx = rtree.index.Index(stream)
     74 
---> 75     idxmatch = (left_df.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.bounds)
     76                 .apply(lambda x: list(tree_idx.intersection(x))))
     77     idxmatch = idxmatch[idxmatch.apply(len) > 0]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3192             else:
   3193                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3194                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3195 
   3196         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\sjoin.py in <lambda>(x)
     73     tree_idx = rtree.index.Index(stream)
     74 
---> 75     idxmatch = (left_df.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.bounds)
     76                 .apply(lambda x: list(tree_idx.intersection(x))))
     77     idxmatch = idxmatch[idxmatch.apply(len) > 0]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\point.py in bounds(self)
    120     @property
    121     def bounds(self):
--> 122         xy = self.coords[0]
    123         return (xy[0], xy[1], xy[0], xy[1])
    124 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried to separate `polys_gdf` in two, one with only polygons, and one with only multipolygons. But I receive the same error.
Can anybody help me out here?

Working code that recreates the error:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

point_list = [Point(),Point(0.5,0.5)]
poly_list = [Polygon([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]])]

points_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=point_list)
polys_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=poly_list)

return_df = gpd.sjoin(points_gdf, polys_gdf, how="inner", op='within')
```

Comment: Just a question, as I can't reproduce this: what is the version of shapely that you have? (if it is a reproducible error, we should fix it in GeoPandas)

Comment: I have shapely version 1.6.4. I will try to upload a reproducible code.

Comment: Hmm, strange, also with 1.6.4, something like `Polygon([]).bounds` works for me (returning empty tuple)

Comment: I added minimal code that reproduces the error.

Comment: Thanks! I tried an empty Polygon, but indeed for an empty Point, that raises this error. That seems a bug in shapely itself, I opened an issue here: https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/716

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just after posting, I found the mistake: I had some empty shapely points in my point_gdf. After deleting them, sjoin() works like a charm.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

point_list = [Point(),Point(0.5,0.5)]
poly_list = [Polygon([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]])]

points_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=point_list)
polys_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=poly_list)

points_gdf = points_gdf[~points_gdf.geometry.is_empty] # delete empty points
return_df = gpd.sjoin(points_gdf, polys_gdf, how="inner", op='within')
```